# Does there exist a mono-spaced (fixed-width) font for all Unicode characters?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, font-design, unicode, communication

Does there exist a font for all 149,186 characters in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) such that every character, or symbol, in the font has the same width as any other character?

It is very difficult to write python scripts in a mixture of English and [georgian script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_scripts) without using a font where every letter has the same width as all other letters.

```python
# დაბეჭდეთ იგი ახლავე ქაღალდზე
print("  " + "the thing" + "  ".strip())
print("  " + "ნივთი" + "  ".strip())
ბეჭდვა("ნივთი")
# ლ(╹◡╹ლ) )
```

The example, does not show it, but indentation is critical for making computer code readable.

```
# for any two words `kidw` and `adultw`
∀ `kidw`, `adultw` ∈ 
    # word `kidw` is simpler than word `adultw`
    `kidw` ≺ `adultw`
        ⟺ # if and only if 
    group (
        the set of people who understand `adultw`
            is a subset of ⊆
        the set of people who understand `kidw`
    ) 
  

# Example:
#     "glue" is a simpler English word than "adhesive"
```

Comment: There is always the option of making your own font to match your exact needs. It is suprisingly hard to find a font when you have exacting niche requirements. Also before you say it, yes making a font is a lot of work... But mainly because of kerning. Monotype fonts dont have that so you save yourself 90% of the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too much for a comment, not definitive enough for a true answer;)*
The three fonts I know of that are reasonably comprehensive are [Deja Vu](https://github.com/dejavu-fonts/dejavu-fonts), [Arial](https://catalog.monotype.com/font/milieu-grotesque/arial/monospaced) & [Noto](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Mono). Each of these has a monospace variation.
*Late edit -* Doing some limited testing, it would appear of these only Deja Vu has Georgian in monospace.

Apple's Menlo also covers most of Georgian - it's the default mono font & I can see [but not read;) all the monospace text on this page.
I'm not really sure how to test all this properly, outside of Apple's own ecosystem, but this is what I have access to - with fonts & variations on my own Mac…

[image]

The first alternative is Ariel. All the others are Deja Vu. I don't have Noto installed.
This is how I see the code block from above - using Apple's default Menlo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, not an easy one. Not a lot of fonts support Georgian. [ParaType's version of the Courier family](https://catalog.monotype.com/family/paratype/courier) says it supports Georgian, also the Mac system font Menlo says it does. Am not qualified to test this, though.